# Aggregate Objects

Tags: oop, object, aggregation

If you have a class A that is an aggregate of class B and C, is it better for A

- to store ID's for B and C
- to load and store the entire object for B and C (edit, store by reference to object B/C, i.e. instantiate objects B and C as opposed to storing id's for B and C.
- store the ID's and provide methods to pull methods B and C

I'm assuming this varies depending on performance requirements and other requierements, but I'm just looking for any general guidelines or thoughts.

Comment: Are you talking COM aggregation?

Comment: What do you mean with "store". If you have objects you don't need IDs because you have instances. Is this database related

Comment: well I'm not using COM, but I'm looking for a more abstract answer than one tied to a particular language/object model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical program running in memory, objects will almost always be stored by reference as pointers, so you ARE storing IDs for B and C, it's just that you don't deal with the details yourself, the language hides them from you.

Loading and storing the "Entire Object" is a questionable concept.  I know you are trying to be language independent, but one of the first things that really helped me "Get" OO is that nearly every object should have a lifecycle of its own.

If you have object A that "Contains" object B, and you pass a reference to object B to object C, then Object A has to know something about object C, this is completely NOT OK.  Freeing up object B's lifecycle so that object A knows nothing of object C is one of the core concepts that makes OO work.

So if that's what you meant by storing the entire object, then no--never do that.

And that's true of Databases and other storage as well.  Even if one object is responsible  for destroying another, it should rarely contain the other objects' data.

And (although I think you meant to say "pull Objects B and C", not "methods"), the concept of being able to pass an object from another is also very useful and there is generally nothing wrong with it with one caveat:

Remember that an object has no control over what goes on outside itself.  It could be passed around, methods called in a semi-random order, etc.  Therefore it's helpful to keep your object as safe as possible.  If something is called in the wrong order, or an invalid variable is passed in, or you find that somehow you've entered an invalid state, Fail early and Fail LOUD so that the programmer who made a mistake called it.

You also want to make it as difficult as possible to get into an illegal state--this means keep your object small and simple, make variables final whenever possible and try not to have too many places where parameter call order matters.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that.

Comment: Sorry if I missed the question a little.  I get the feeling you were referring to something slightly different that applies to some specific language/toolkit that I don't use--so I feel like I was probably off base.

Comment: no i think you answered fairly well, it's hard to ask questions like these and be crystal clear

Answer (score 2):

I tend to load and store the entire objects (and their subobjects) as my default approach.

Sometimes this will cause long load times, a large memory footprint, or both.  Then you'll need to determine if all the loaded objects are in fact used or if many are created and never accessed.

If all the objects are used, a more creative approach will be needed to load a subset, process those, dispose them, and then load the next subset to fit everything into memory - or simply buy more memory and make it available to your app.

If many of the objects are not used, the best approach is to lazily load the sub-objects as they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the situation.  If the objects stay in memory, it's more OO (and easier) to have A contain B and C.  I've found that if the objects need to be persisted, though, it makes things easier and more efficient for A to store IDs for B and C.  (That way if you need data directly in A but not B and C, you won't have to pull B and C out of the database, file, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends,

If B and C are heavy and expense to load and construct, it might be worthwhile to defer the loading of them until you are sure they are needed (Lazy Initialize).

If they are simple and lightweight maybe you just want to construct them whenever, you get the Ids.